# Weird bug with the parallel package: paragraphs not aligned

Tags: parallel

With the following code...

```
\documentclass[draft,10pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\usepackage{parallel}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\section{My Section}  % kill this line and the result is OK

BAD: % or kill this line and the result is ok

\begin{Parallel}{.47\textwidth}{.47\textwidth}
\ParallelLText{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
\ParallelRText{Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.}
\end{Parallel}

\bigskip

GOOD:

\begin{Parallel}{.47\textwidth}{.47\textwidth}  % same as above...
\ParallelLText{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
\ParallelRText{Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.}
\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

I get this result:

[image]

See the blank line between "BAD" and "Lorem ipsum"?

To me, it seems like a `parallel` bug. I know there are other package for typesetting parallel text, such as `paracol` or `parcolumns`, but usually I have better results with `parallel` (fewer widows for instance).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Placing `~\par\vskip -\baselineskip` before the `BAD` line provides a workaround, but not really a fix.

Comment: parallel overwrites the `\everypar` set by `\@afterheading` and so `\clubpenalty` is not reset correctly after the first paragraph ("BAD"). You could add `\makeatletter\clubpenalty \@clubpenalty\makeatother` before `\begin{parallel}`.

Comment: My code for the parallel text is actually inside a macro and the command you mentioned failed with a "spacefactor" error, because of the "@". So I added \clubpenalty=500 before \begin{parallel} (inside the macro), and this fixes the bug. Thanks a lot for your hint, Ulrike!

Answer (score 3):

Package `parallel` overwrites the `\everypar` set by `\@afterheading` and so `\clubpenalty` is not reset correctly after the first paragraph ("BAD"). You could add `\makeatletter\clubpenalty \@clubpenalty\makeatother` before `\begin{parallel}`.